# dplyr separate returning error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Trying to separate the Results Column from df2 into 2 separate columns ("Winner", "Loser" and remove the numbers from each new column with the below code but get the following error message. What changes need to be made to correct?

```
df2 <- data.frame(Year = c(2015:1903 ), Results = c("Winner", "Loser"))
df2 %>% separate(type, c("Winner", "Loser"), ",")

Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  :
argument is of length zero
```

df2

```
    Year                              Results                 MVP
1   2015                          Royals 4, Mets 1      Salvador Perez
2   2014                        Giants 4, Royals 3   Madison Bumgarner
3   2013                    Red Sox 4, Cardinals 2         David Ortiz
4   2012                        Giants 4, Tigers 0      Pablo Sandoval
5   2011                    Cardinals 4, Rangers 3        David Freese
.
.
125 1906       Chicago White Sox 4, Chicago Cubs 2                  --
126 1905           NY Giants 4, Philadelphia A's 1                  --
128 1903            Boston Red Sox 5, Pittsburgh 3                  --
```

Comment: Have you tested the `df2 <- data.frame(...`  It is giving me error

Comment: you can also use `separate_`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution with `separate()`. In your code, you have `type` in `separate()`. You may want to double check that. Here I created a sample data frame called `df2` and did the following. First, I removed space and numbers in `Results`. Then, I separated the column using `separate()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mutate(df2, Results = gsub(pattern = "\\s|\\d+", replacement = "", x = Results)) %>%
separate(col = "Results", into = c("Winner", "Loser"), sep = ",")

#  Year    Winner     Loser
#1 2000    Royals      Mets
#2 2001    Giants    Royals
#3 2002    RedSox Cardinals
#4 2003    Giants    Tigers
#5 2004 Cardinals   Rangers
```

**DATA**

```
df2 <- structure(list(Year = 2000:2004, Results = c("Royals 4, Mets 1", 
"Giants 4, Royals 3", "Red Sox 4, Cardinals 2", "Giants 4, Tigers 0", 
"Cardinals 4, Rangers 3")), .Names = c("Year", "Results"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

#  Year                Results
#1 2000       Royals 4, Mets 1
#2 2001     Giants 4, Royals 3
#3 2002 Red Sox 4, Cardinals 2
#4 2003     Giants 4, Tigers 0
#5 2004 Cardinals 4, Rangers 3
```

Comment: @danielhong Pleasure. :)

Comment: if you don't mind, a follow up question, when i try to summarise the winner and losers i cannot do so, do i need  to create a new data.frame?

Comment: @danielhong Do you want to count the frequency of each winner-loser pair?

Comment: ateempting to count the frequency of winners and losers independently

Comment: @danielhong It seems that you want to summarize the data. You probably wanna add the following line `summarize(w = n_distinct(Winner), l = n_distinct(Loser))`

Comment: this is not running, is it possible to create a separate df? '> summarize(w = n_distinct(Winner), l = n_distinct(Loser))
Error in is.data.frame(.data) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
> '

Comment: @danielhong I wanted you to run the summarize code with my answer like this. `mutate(df2, Results = gsub(pattern = "\\s|\\d+", replacement = "", x = Results)) %>% separate(col = "Results", into = c("Winner", "Loser"), sep = ",") %>% summarize(w = n_distinct(Winner), l = n_distinct(Loser))` You pipe your operation with `%>%`. Just running the summarize code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with a single call using `tidyr::extract` (using @jazzurros data)

```
extract(df2, 
        "Results", c("Winner", "Loser"), 
        "([[:alpha:] ]+)\\s+\\d+,\\s+([[:alpha:] ]+)\\s+\\d+")
#   Year    Winner     Loser
# 1 2000    Royals      Mets
# 2 2001    Giants    Royals
# 3 2002   Red Sox Cardinals
# 4 2003    Giants    Tigers
# 5 2004 Cardinals   Rangers
```